# Prove that a finite group of order $16$ has a non-trivial normal-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $16$, and $\pi$ a $G$ action on a set $X$, where $|X|=5$.
>
> We also know that in $G$ there are only $5$ sub-groups of order $4$.
>
> Prove that $G$ has a non-trivial normal sub-group.

Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a $p$-group as it's order is of the form $p^k$(precisely $2^4$), and center of a $p$-group is non-trivial and center is a normal subgroup, hence done!

[Part of simple proof of nontrivial center in p-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982985/part-of-simple-proof-of-nontrivial-center-in-p-group)

Comment: Does it matter that there are only $5$ sub-groups of order $4$?

Comment: No, not required

Comment: I suspect that this answer would/will not get full marks. There is a strong implication that you are supposed to prove it by using the fact that there are (exactly) $5$ subgroups of order $4$, which is possible.

Comment: Sorry but why does G have $5$ subgroups of order $4$?