# Any group $G$ of order $200$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup that is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to prove the title. I have shown that there exists a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$:

$$|G|=200=5^2\cdot8$$

$\implies$the amount $s_5$ of 5-Sylow subgroups of $G$ divides $8$ and $s_5\equiv1\mod{5}$

$\Longleftrightarrow$ $s_5\in\{1,2,4,8\}\cap\{1+5k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{1\}$

$\implies$the 5-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is a (non-trivial) normal subgroup of $G$

---

My question: How can I show that there exists an **abelian** non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$?

Also please let me know if you see any mistakes in my proof

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212084/group-with-order-p2-must-be-abelian-how-to-prove-that) question.

Comment: @DonThousand I don't quite understand [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/999281/676656) answer. Why is $|G/Z(G)|=1$ or $p$?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982985/part-of-simple-proof-of-nontrivial-center-in-p-group) question.