# Center of nonabelian groups of order $p^3$ ($p$ prime) and commutator subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**Problem:** If $G$ is a nonabelian group of order $p^3$ ($p$ prime), then the center of $G$ is the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $aba^{-1} b^{-1}$ ($a,b\in G$).

I know that $Z(G)$ must have order $p$ for $G$ to be nonabelian. I'm working with the equation for finite subgroups trying to reach a contradiction but I don't see it yet.

\begin{equation}
|[G,G]Z(G)| = \frac{|[G,G]|\cdot|Z(G)|}{|[G,G]\cap Z(G)|}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Any group of order  $p^2$ is abelian.   Also, the center of a $p $-group is nontrivial.   So the center has order $p $ (otherwise it has order  $p^2$, the quotient is cyclic of order  $p $, and this implies that the group is abelian).

Then $G/Z (G) $ is abelian.   Thus $[G,G]\le Z (G) $.  Thus $[G,G]=Z (G) $.

Comment: Why $[G,G]=Z (G) $ ?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of future readers, I'd like to add some clarification on the solution which has been posted before.

First, note that [the center of a $p$-group is nontrivial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982985/part-of-simple-proof-of-nontrivial-center-in-p-group)  Hence, the center is of order either $p$ or $p^2$. $|Z(G)|=p^2$ is impossible because $|Z(G)|=p^2$ implies that $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|=p$, and hence $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is cyclic. Therefore, [$G$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian), which is against our assumption.

Therefore, $|Z(G)|=p$, and $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|=p^2$. [Since any group of order $p^2$ is abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64371/showing-group-with-p2-elements-is-abelian) , we conclude that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is **abelian**. Now, for all $x,y \in G$, we have:
$(xZ(G))(yZ(G))=(yZ(G))(xZ(G))$. So,
$$1Z(G)=(xZ(G))^{-1}(yZ(G))^{-1}(xZ(G))(yZ(G)) \\ =x^{-1}y^{-1}xyZ(G)=[x,y]Z(G).$$

Thus, $[x,y]\in Z(G)$ for all $x,y\in G$, so $[G,G] \leq Z(G)$. However, note that $Z(G)$ is a group of order $p$ whose only subgroups are $e$ and $Z(G)$. Since $[G,G]$ is nontrivial (if it were trivial, $G$ would have been abelian), we must have $[G,G]=Z(G).$