# Serre's proof that every $p$-group is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

The following is an excerpt from section 8.3 of *Représentations linéaires des groupes finis* by J.-P. Serre.

> $\textbf{Theorem 14.}$ Every $p$-group is nilpotent.
>
> In view of the preceding, it suffices to show that the centre of every non-trivial $p$-group is non-trivial.

He then goes on to show that if $G$ is a $p$-group, then $p$ divides $\lvert Z(G)\rvert$, thereby proving that the centre is non-trivial.

My question is: Why does it suffice to show that the centre is non-trivial?

He says it is "in view of the preceding / vu ce qui précède", but the preceding is just a definition of various classes of finite groups (soluble/supersoluble/nilpotent/$p$-groups).

If anyone out there has read the book and understood the proof, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1951147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If you divide out the centre of a $p$- group, you get ...

Hint 2: Induction.