# Is a group of prime-power order always abelian?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n$, with $p$ prime. By Sylow's first theorem, there exists at least one  subgroup of order $p^n$ (the number of subgroups of order $p^i$ is $1$ mod $p$ per $i$). The subgroups with order $p^n$ are all Sylow-$p$ groups.

Now, by Sylow's third theorem, because the group is of order $p^n$, the number $m_{p^{n}}$ of such subgroups must divide $\#G/p^n =1$, and only $1$ divides $1$, so there is only one subgroup of order $p^n$.

By Sylow's second theorem, all Sylow-$p$ groups are conjugated to each other by at least one element $g\in G$, so, for any $S$ and $S'$, we have $S=gS'g^{-1}$. In this case, there is only one Sylow-$p$ group, so it is conjugated to itself.

Of course, that one subgroup is the group itself. We now have $gG=Gg$ for some $g$ in $G$. *Can we get to the entire group being abelian, from here?*

I ask because my textbook on Abstract Algebra states that any group of order $p^2$ is abelian, and I'm curious whether it generalises.

**Edit:** As has been pointed out, everything I've proved above is quite trivial. Below it is discussed that the essential question is actually "*How does one prove that groups of order $p^2$ are abelian using Sylow theory?*", since my textbook explicitly mentions this property as an application of Sylow's theorems.

**Edit 2:** One of the authors has confirmed that they accidentally mixed some classic classification theorems into the list of applications of Sylow theory, and that this was one of them.

Comment: Hint:  look at groups of order $8$.

Comment: Nope—consider $D_4$, the dihedral group with eight elements

Comment: Ah, thanks, the both of you. Any idea which further steps are needed to prove that it _does_ work for $n=2$?

Comment: Are the first two paragraphs necessary? Isn't the only subgroup of the same order of the (finite) group the group itself?

Comment: @csn: True. In that sense, the question can be boiled down to "Prove that groups of order $p^2$ are abelian _from the POV of Sylow theory_", see also my comment under hdighfan's answer.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I'll contact the authors, in that case. Thanks for adding.

Comment: You can't really mean that a group of order $p^n$ has at least one subgroup of order $p^n$. True, yes, but not very illuminating.

Comment: @TonyK: On the other hand, proofs by induction would be much nastier if mathematics didn't allow for evidencies to be made explicit. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't generalise -- the dihedral group with $8$ elements is an example, and a more general one is the set of matrices $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & y \\ 0 & 1 & z \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z_p}$.

For a group of order $p^2$, the most common way to prove that it is abelian is to look at its center, $Z(G)$, the set of terms which commute with every other term. The center has to be nontrivial: if you consider the conjugacy classes of $G$ on itself, each must be of size $p^k$ for some non-negative $k$. But the conjugacy class of $e$ is trivial, and thus there exist at least $p-1$ other such cases.

Suppose the center has size $p$. Then $G/Z(G)$ must be a cyclic group on $p$ elements, and thus $G$ must be abelian. (for any group $H$, if $H/Z(H)$ is cyclic then $Z(H)=H$).

Comment: Alright. Is my proof a dead-end, as far as proving $n=2$ goes? I've seen the proof using the centre floating around, but I was never taught about the centre of a group, and since the property w.r.t. $p^2$ is mentioned in the context of Sylow theory (but without proof, sadly), I'm wondering whether I can work from that angle.

Comment: What csn said in the last comment is quite accurate. Everything you've proven is trivial -- for any element $g\in G$, $gG=Gg$, so that's saying nothing. The preceding two paragraphs are actually even more trivial. In general, Sylow's theorems applied directly to $p$-sylows are trivial and don't tell you anything.

Comment: I see what you both mean; it's indeed all trivial in the end. Again, though, it makes me wonder why the textbook would state the commutativity of groups of order $p^2$ directly inside an enumeration "Applications of Sylow's theorems". I was in the headspace of Sylow's theorems, and thus thought it'd only make so much sense to prove it that way.

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. It could be that results stemming from the proof of the Sylow theorems can be used, but that depends on how they were proved, of course.

Comment: The class formula, which is essentially how you showed that the center is nontrivial, is an ingredient of a rather standard proof of the Sylow theorems.

Comment: I contacted the authors, and it turns out this was an error on their part: they mixed up unrelated classification theorems into the applications of Sylow theory. There's the answer. (This is the university's AbsAlg textbook, so not much scrutiny happened before publishing.)

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a nonabelian group of order $p^n$, for $p$ an odd prime, $n\gt2$,  by selecting a nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi:\Bbb Z_p\to\rm{Aut}(\Bbb Z_{p^{n-1}})\cong\Bbb Z_{p^{n-1}-p^{n-2}}$.  Let $G=\Bbb Z_{p^{n-1}}\rtimes_\varphi\Bbb Z_p$.

If, on the other hand, $p=2$, consider dihedral groups.

Answer (score 3):

A group of order $p^n$ is always *nilpotent*. This is a natural generalisation of abelian. The examples of $Q_8$ and $D_4$ of order $8$ are nilpotent but non-abelian. The group of upper-unitriangular matrices over $\Bbb F_p$ is the Heisenberg group, which is $2$-step nilpotent, and also non-abelian.

Reference:
[Prove that every finite p-group is nilpotent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140381/prove-that-every-finite-p-group-is-nilpotent)